# subgit installation on TFS git repo

Tags: subgit

Is anyone installed Subgit on TFS managed git repository? Is two sync working on your installation?

I had installed subgit on TFS server and sync is not working for me.

If you have installed subgit on TFS managed git, could you please explain,

where did you install or run subgit?. 
 How did you captured git path in TFS server?.

As far as i know, In TFS server Files aren’t stored on the file system, Instead they’re stored in the TFS SQL server databases.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Subgit installation on TFS Maintained Git repo](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40479733/subgit-installation-on-tfs-maintained-git-repo)